# How to turn on color for text/button field according to the json input from db using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json

i want to give colors to the text/button field in the webpage according to the json output data from the database. how to do that in angularjs?

for example, i am storing the Boolean value for particular field in database.
if the value 0 mean false and 1 mean true. if the data for the particular field returns json data 0 then UI color should be RED and for the json data 1 means then color should be BLUE.

[click here for sample image type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VbJ2.png)
g

Comment: First, don't represent a boolean by a number. Represent a boolean by a boolean. Then, use ng-class: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: you can use ng-class and base it of the output you get from your json, ng-class="{green: item=1}"

Comment: @nCore you mean `ng-class="{green: item === 1}"`

Comment: yeah sorry forgot the curly braces.

Comment: and you used an assignment operator rather than an ehality operator.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet for the help.
i want to left the another option with out any color like as in the image? can u share the codes pls?